# Making save to SD card and Context Menu functions dynamic, or relative to button pressed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdcard, android-context

Relative to the below code, how do I make

```
if (savering(R.raw.sound1)){
```

and

```
String filename=”sound1″+”.ogg”;
```

and

```
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, “sound1″);
```

dynamic instead of static so that the sound file that will be saved is based on the button pressed?

My sound files are in a soundArray saved as sound1, sound2, sound3, etc. There is a button for each sound file. Click to play, long click brings up the below context menu.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
//CONTEXT MENU

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Notification");
    }
    @Override   
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
     if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}   
      else if(item.getTitle()=="Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
      else {return false;}
     return true; 
    }

    public void function1(int id){  
     if 
     (savering(R.raw.sound1)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

    }
    public void function2(int id){   
     if 
     (savenot(R.raw.sound1)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }
    }

//Save into Ring tone Folder

    public boolean savering(int ressound){
     byte[] buffer=null;
     InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
     int size=0; 

     try {
       size = fIn.available();   
       buffer = new byte[size];   
       fIn.read(buffer);   
       fIn.close(); 
     } catch (IOException e) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
      return false;      } 

     String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";
     String filename="sound1"+".ogg"; 

     boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
     if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}   

     FileOutputStream save;
     try { 
      save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);   
      save.write(buffer);   
      save.flush();   
      save.close();   
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
      return false;  
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
      return false;
     }
     sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename))); 

     File k = new File(path, filename);   
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();   
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());   
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "sound1 Ringtone");   
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");   
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");   
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);   
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);   
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);   
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);    

     //Insert it into the database
     this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

     return true; 
    }

//Save in Notification Folder

    public boolean savenot(int ressound){
     byte[] buffer=null;
     InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
     int size=0; 

     try {
       size = fIn.available();   
       buffer = new byte[size];   
       fIn.read(buffer);   
       fIn.close(); 
     } catch (IOException e) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
      return false;      } 

     String path="/sdcard/media/audio/notifications/";
     String filename="sound1"+".ogg"; 

     boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
     if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}   

     FileOutputStream save;
     try { 
      save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);   
      save.write(buffer);   
      save.flush();   
      save.close();   
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
      return false;  
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
      return false;
     }
     sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename))); 

     File k = new File(path, filename);   
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();   
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());   
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "sound1 Notification");   
     values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");   
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");   
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);   
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);   
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);   
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);    

     //Insert it into the database
     this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

     return true; 
    }
```

Comment: pls can you elaborate how the what the menu items have you.it is sound files each on ur menu item?

Comment: Yes, there is a button displayed for each soundfile

Comment: so you rae able to get id for each menu item of ringtone?

Comment: I can get id for each view or sound resource, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can got solution by using following changes:

1: take two arrays. one for storing your ringbuttons ids which you are adding to menu to play and another array respectively with corresponding sound array id for that button's sound;

For example,

```
int btnid=new int[count];//count is no of buttons for playing ring
int rawid=ne int[count];
```

Then you can catch the id of button of clicked menuitem and from that you have to compare in function1 with your btnid array and get the index of array of btnid matched.

2: than after with same index you can find rawsource in rawid array.

---

Your first problem is solved, now for that second prob of filename you just try this:

```
String filename="sound"+id+".ogg";//id is index of array
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will be honest, I am not quite sure how to implement all of your suggestions as I constructed my sound array using a suggestion I read and it is done differently. Also I am not quite sure how to pass the id of the array index to the savering function but this is definately helpful. I really appreciate your taking the time to offer some assistance. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, so I made the arrays using the shortcut syntax int[] anArray = {R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2, etc.}; R.id.sound1, etc. for the buttons. I don't know how to use them, to catch the index number and pass it to the functions in the activity. All the tutorials I have found end at making the index, they don't include using it.

Comment: aron you can get menuitemid from menu click.ok.so according to it you have to figure out frm which id ur ring button menu items start and acoording it you can figure out index.its now you have to implement logic.

Comment: Thanks. I can appreciate the concept but don't know how to excecute it. Could you by chance show me an example of how I would do this?